# Adding HTML into the <head> HTML tag for all MediaWiki web pages

Tags: mediawiki

How to add HTML into the  HTML tag for all MediaWiki web pages?

- In `/skins/mySkin/includes/mySkinTemplate.php` I didn't find anything that does with `<head>`.
- I found no global template file and I prefer not to use a hook for that.

How would you do it?

Comment: This is a programming issue and off topic for here. I would direct you to Stack Overflow but your question would not be allowed there either as it is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I used this JavaScript way to add HTML code to `<head>` for all pages via `?title=MediaWiki:Common.js`:

```
var templateLiteral = [`
    <!-- HTML_CODE_COMES_HERE -->
`]

var head = document.querySelector("head");
head.innerHTML = templateLiteral;
```

I then checked a webpage and saw the code was added to HTML source.

Comment: Hello, I would be happy to know what's bad with the answer. If I was wrong in anything, I'd gladly remove it... This worked for me and made the relevant API recognize my site, hence I don't understand the down vote.

Comment: Your whole question, and two others on this platform, are off topic and should have been closed. Webmasters is not about coding at all. Such questions belong on Stack Overflow instead. Why all three were not deleted immediately is completely bizarre to me but it happens often here. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: "How do I add HTML into a tag" is never a marketing issue.

Comment: Sorry, I confused with another question to which this issue is relevant (behind the scenes). I will delete what I wrote above and suggest comment deletion.